# How to find the recurring words in an analyzed field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, aggregate-functions

I have an analyzed field in my index named `content` .

I'd like to get the number of words occurred in documents.

Comment: From a specific document? If so, have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET /your-index-name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "your-field-name": "*"
    }
  },
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "whatever-name-you-want-like-your-field-name-agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "your-field-name",
        "size": 100 
      }
    }
  }
}`

First `Size` is appears to remove the document containing the words list from the response.

Second `Size` is the size of returned list showing the most recurring words.